# Create a matrix with ones on any offset diagonal

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm aiming for a function that creates matrices with ones on offset diagonals:

[image]

So similar to the `eye(5)` function, but now on offset diagonals. Preferably not using double `for` loops. I do not want the full matrix, rather I have to insert them into an existing matrix. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`diag`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) has this functionality built in:

```
diag(ones(4,1),1)
ans =

     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0

diag(ones(4,1),-1)

ans =

     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
```

Where the syntax of `diag(V,k)` is: `V` is the vector to be put on the diagonal (be it ones, or any odd vector), and `k` is the label of the diagonal. `0` is the main diagonal, positive integers are increasingly further away upper diagonals and negative integers the same for the lower diagonals; i.e. `k=1` gives the first upper diagonal, `k=-4` gives the lower left corner in this example.

For completeness, if you just want the indices instead of a full matrix (since you suggested you wanted to insert a vector into a present matrix) you can use the following function:

```
function [idx] = diagidx(n,k)
% n size of square matrix
% k number of diagonal
if k==0 % identity
    idx = [(1:n).' (1:n).']; % [row col]
elseif k>0 % Upper diagonal
    idx = [(1:n-k).' (1+k:n).'];
elseif k<0 % lower diagonal
    idx = [(1+abs(k):n).' (1:n-abs(k)).'];
end
end
```

where each row of `idx` contains the indices for the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
triu(B+1,1)-triu(B+1,2)
```

creates ones on the first upper off-diagonal, and

```
tril(B+1,-2)-tril(B+1,-3)
```

does the same for the first lower off-diagonal.

Comment: When your matrix is e.g. 1000x1000, you create 999+998+...+1 ones, then subtract 998+997+...+1 ones from it. It works, but I doubt this will be faster than a JIT-optimised loop for very big matrices, due to the enormous amount of subtractions you perform.

Comment: I should have been more specific in my question. I have to insert them into an existing matrix. But I suppose I could use the offset parameter in diag to also reduce the matrix size it generates. Then add it to the existing matrix

Comment: Even when inserting them into an existing matrix, you still create a mask, either with `diag` or with `triu` right? In that case, I'd go for the `diag(ones())` option, make that a logical mask (or use `subs2ind`) then index your vector into your matrix.