# MATLAB imread reads a color GIF as gray-scale

Tags: matlab, image-processing

When I try to read the following GIF image using `imread`:

[image]

I get to see this gray-scale image instead:

[image]

This is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISgSJ.gif');
imshow(img)
```

MATLAB reads other images correctly. What is wrong with this particular image? How should I read it?

Comment: It's impossible to tell, given that you've provided no relevant information.

Comment: It is an indexed image, if you are looking for the term

Comment: Do you guys with the MATLAB gold badge not close questions anymore? See [this  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52200040/create-a-matrix-with-ones-on-any-offset-diagonal) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52181772/matlab-rename-plot-title-automatically-with-loop).

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: if you want to help moderate the MATLAB tag, please join us in the [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/chatlab-and-talktave).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This GIF image has a color map. You need to read the color map in separately and use it for display:

```
[img, cm] = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISgSJ.gif');
imshow(img, cm)
```

To convert the image to an RGB image, use [`ind2rgb`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2rgb.html):

```
img = ind2rgb(img, cm);
```